# How long should the maximum length of an exr sequence be?

Tags: after-effects, formats

I'm wondering if there is a maximum length for an exr image sequence or an image sequence in general. In After Effects I'm having trouble to load long exr image sequences

The Image sequence is loading fine to a certain length and then it doesn't load the following frames it either shows them like the footage is not connected (colored test screen) or it shows the last frame that was successfully loaded.

Comment: How long it is exactly?

Comment: 10700 Frames long

Comment: There is no limit. Maybe there is a composition length maximum, but I think that's around 3 hours.

Comment: Sounds more like  a bug - do you get error messages? Can you explain your trouble in detail?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question - you can try to open up the frame(s) in another tool (blender, fusion, nuke, natron). If it works fine - send a bug report to adobe.

Comment: Seems like a bug it is loading fine in NUKE.

Comment: Nice :) Please report it for all of us and hopefully they will fix it soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report.

Comment: Found out that this was a problem with my hard drive formatting.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience @Benedikt! It was FAT32 formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the frame after it stops loading, it could be a corrupt file that causes After Effects to stop loading the rest of the files.

Comment: If I separate the frames in folders of 1000 frames and load them in one after the other it seems to work all fine.

Comment: That is a strange behavior. It really does sound like a bug. I've used image sequences that exceeded more than 10k frames.

Comment: In After Effects?

Comment: Yes, you might want to try to use a newer version of fnord'S OpenEXR plugin: http://www.fnordware.com/OpenEXR/
 Its free and included in the trial download for ProEXR for PS.